# Verbs not normally used in the present continuous

Tags: present-tense, continuous-aspect, stative-verbs

I found the information below in a grammar book:

> The following verbs are not normally used in the present continuous :
>   like, love, hate, want, need, prefer, know, realize, suppose, mean, understand, believe, remember, belong, fit, contain, consist, seem.

1. Are there any other verbs which are not used in present continuous?
2. If yes, why are the above verbs not used in present continuous?

Comment: I'm loving your question!

Comment: ... but seriously, I think "I'm loving" is a modern habit that started in advertising, and to me suggests fickleness [just now, I'm loving X's flat whites, but who knows what I'll love tomorrow?].  In truth, liking, loving and hating are states that last too long to apply to the present continuous. 'Want' is an oddity, tho: it would be reasonable to want something at the moment and not later, so "I'm wanting a coffee" *ought* to make sense.

Comment: And for *fit*, it depends on the meaning. We probably wouldn't say *"this shoe is fitting me perfectly"*, but there's nothing wrong with *"the tailor is fitting the suit for him now"*.

Comment: I am not understanding the relevance of the "if yes" in question 2.

Comment: "If yes" in the above question means that only 18 words (like ~seem) are not use in present continuous.

Comment: A more extensive [list](http://esl.about.com/od/grammarintermediate/a/noncontinuous.htm)

Answer (score 3):

The words on the OP list are:

> - *states* (know, understand, remember, etc.),
> - *general realities* (belong, fit, contain, consist, seem, etc.),
> - *emotions* and *wishes* (like, love, hate, etc.)

Though experienced in a continuous aspect, they tend to transcend present time.

Examples:

> - *I **know** 15 digits of pi, because I memorized them in eighth grade, and will not forget them until my brain disintegrates.*
> - *I **belong** to the human race just like my parents did, my children do, and my grandchildren will.*
> - *I **like** reading, have liked it longer than I can remember, and probably always will.*

*States*, *general realities*, *emotions* and *wishes* are part of the [simple present](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_present) aspect:

> It is commonly referred to as a tense, although it also encodes
>   certain information about **aspect** in addition to present time.
>   [Discussion omitted]...
>   [C]ertain verbs expressing a **state**, such as
>   be and know, are used in the simple present even when referring to a
>   temporary present state. [Discussion omitted]...
>
> - To refer to an action or event that takes place habitually. In the other hand to remark habits, **general realities**, **repeated actions** or **unchanging situations**, **emotions** and **wishes**. [Examples omitted]...
> - With **stative** verbs in senses that do not use progressive aspect (see [Uses of English verb forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#Progressive): Progressive), to refer to a present or general state, whether temporary, permanent or habitual.
>
> **Emphasis** mine

Even with active verbs, *I eat*, engages past, present and future simultaneously, while *I am eating* emphasizes the present.

General reference *Wikipedia.org*