# The slogan, "i'm lovin' it" is grammatically wrong

Tags: grammar, colloquialisms

My grammar book pointed out that when you use some verbs in the continuous tenses, it need to be something active, such as running, or eating.
Verbs that do not imply an action, but instead refer to a state of affairs - for example, know, own, love, or feel -can not be used in the continuous tenses. If so, is there any verb list which I can not use in the continuous tenses? It makes me confuse and easily make mistake if I am not careful. So as native English speaking people.

Comment: Not entirely correct. "Feel" can be used in the present tense: "I am feeling [object]."

Comment: I think you're **being** too restrictive in your use of the progressive form of verbs.

Comment: I"m not sure about the general claim concerning verbs that do not imply an action. "I'm sitting here" sounds OK to me even though sitting isn't an action. But I agree that "I'm loving it" is not something one would ordinarily say. That might be why it was chosen as a slogan; things we don't ordinarily say attract more attention.

Comment: So do you think my grammar book's explanation is not correct?

Comment: Also, most people do not even notice about this slogan's grammatically wrong. Of course, they do not say it but they do not care grammar of this phrases.

Comment: If your grammar book is any good, it should say the progressive tense is not *normally* used for stative/non-action verbs. I'm guessing the book is aimed at pre-intermediate, possibly intermediate level learners. An advanced level book will not make such a black and white statement. Remember that English is incredibly flexible, and it is constantly mutating. It is a living creature that survives in today's world, and no longer leans towards or looks upon  Latin for guidance.

Comment: related: [**Verbs not normally used in the present continuous**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237282/verbs-not-normally-used-in-the-present-continuous) and on the web: [Non-continuous Verbs](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-m_vmwct_1.htm) and [**"Non-Continuous Verbs,"**... These verbs are usually things you cannot see somebody doing. **These verbs are rarely used in continuous tenses**.](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/types.html)

Comment: Your grammar book has most likely over-simplified and over-generalized the grammar "rules" that it's teaching the students. The grammar is not that simple. There are usages and contexts where that type of construction is acceptable. I think Language Log might have done an article on that topic. :)

Comment: Seems like the author of your grammar book needs to take an English course.

Comment: @Mari-LouA nailed it with her link to: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/im-lovin-it -- high five for her; nicely done.

Comment: Here's a related article: http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2014/03/27/are-you-feeling-it/

Answer (score 2):

I agree with F F. Your grammar book over-simplifies. I am thinking. I am thinking doughnuts. I am feeling hot. I am hearing dissent. I am considering love. I am loving the memory. I am remembering it. I am loving it (so long as the pronoun "it" has been defined by the previous text). I am having no difficulty with any of these!

Comment: What about something much more similar than yours: "I am hating it". Sounds a bit off, somewhat like the over progressive-izing by Indians like "I am wanting to go home now".

Answer (score 1):

What matters for whether you can use the progressive is whether a verb refers to a process.  States are not processes, but actions are ordinarily processes.  Processes needn't be actions.  Processes take some time to happen.  Radioactive decay of uranium is an example of a process that is not a condition and is not an action -- you can perfectly well use the progressive aspect to describe it: "The uranium is decaying rapidly."

Answer (score 0):

**col·lo·qui·al** 
kəˈlōkwēəl
(adjective)

Used in ordinary or familiar conversation; not formal or literary.

synonyms:  informal, conversational, everyday, nonliterary; unofficial, idiomatic, slangy, vernacular, popular, demotic

"He was puzzled by the **colloquial** language of the advertisement."

```
If so, is there any verb list which I can not use in the continuous tenses?
```

Not so much a ***list*** so much as a special usage: **colloquial**.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar book is correct. You would say, "I love grammar," but you wouldn't say, "I am loving grammar." Below are other examples of non-continuous or stative verbs, which don't have a progressive aspect. Many advertisements use incorrect grammar to be cute (and sell hamburgers).

feeling: hate, like, love, prefer, want, wish
senses: appear, feel, hear, see, seem, smell, sound, taste
communication: agree, deny, disagree, mean, promise, satisfy, surprise
thinking: believe, imagine, know, mean, realize, recognize, remember, understand
other states: be, belong, concern, depend, involve, matter, need, owe, own, possess